# Show logs are not coming in Visual SVN 1.5 after upgrading from 1.4.6

Tags: svn, visualsvn

The question is regarding show logs are not coming properly after upgrading.

I upgraded my repository from SVN 1.4.6 from Linux to Visual SVN 1.5 in windows.

Explaining the steps here:

1. I took the complete SVN repo from 1.4.6 SVN - say Repository name as Repo1.4.6
2. I upgraded the SVN1.4.6 using below command

   svnadmin upgrade Repo1.4.6
3. The Repository Repo1.4.6 consists of revisions no. 1 to 1000
4. I took dump of only last 20 revsions from Repo1.4.6
   Command used for the above is:

svnadmin dump Repo1.4.6 -r 980:1000 >DRepo1.4.6

Drepo1.4.6 is dump name.

5. Created a new repository in Visual SVN 1.5 - say repository name as Repo1.5
6. I uploaded to the Dump to new Repo1.5 using the below command

svnadmin load Repo1.5 >DRepo1.4.6

7. Tested the Repo1.5 it has all the 20 revisions correctly. I am able to check in also.
8. But when I access the Repo1.5 through Repo broser of tortoise SVN and checked show logs.The previous log comments of 20 revisions and new revisions are not seen.

Please let me know if any steps I missed out here and help me to see the logs.

Comment: Please expand a bit on your comment, and use complete sentences and properly spelled words. Then we may be able to help you a bit.

Comment: Not everyone on SO is a native speaker...

Comment: There, edited for spelling and grammar.

Comment: BTW... shouldn't you upgraded to 1.6.5 as been the latest version, why 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the log cache in TSVN:

Settings dialog->Saved Data. Click the "clear" button for "log messages (show log dialog)".